Can an ALB be used for an SFTP instance?
Project: SFTP platform Migration. created 2nd instance with new platform, should be able to use existing Security groups.
so far I cant make this work as it appears the ALB wont let me assign a port 22 or other listener.
netops doesnt want to assign an EIP, so need LB for public IP
NLB seems excessive for my traffic, if I use Classic ELB isnt EOL just around the corner?
any help or guidance appreciated.

ALB operate at OSI layer 7 and is bound to the http(s) protocol. you can't use another protocol.
You will need a NLB that operate at OSI layer 4. because it operates at a lower level, it is not bound to any protocol.
